# endl, '\t' and '\n' dont work after 15 tabs

Tags: c++, string, io

If you compile and run this code, the endl doesn't get executed. You will get 0hello when you pop the terminal into full screen.

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    using namespace std;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        cout  << '\t';
    }
    cout << "0" << endl << "hello";

    return 0;
}
```

However, if you use `cout << "00" << endl << "hello";` then it works fine. I don't understand why this happens nor how to fix it.

Comment: Can't reproduce. `hello` comes on the new line as expected for me (and at [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/4r6j5K4ze) too)

Comment: What OS and compiler please ?

Comment: Windows 10 and im using ms visual studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are running this from visual studio where the default terminal width is 120 characters.

A tab is 8 characters. 8x15 = 120.

If you look at the output, there is a blank line before the 0.  It is printing the tabs: just that you've reached the end of line so it has moved to the next line.

If you change the terminal width to 80 characters you might get a different result - a blank line and the 0 in the centre of the page.

Comment: What is interesting though is the 0 is printed at position 120 instead of 121.  The last tab is only 7 character wide and the new line gets discarded.  I stopped this from happening by changing the width property to 122.  The 0 prints at position 121 and the new line works as expected.  It has something to do with the size of the screen buffer.

Comment: When I tried it on VS2010, the 0 appeared on the next line.

Comment: Output is unaffected by the command prompt size when running the compiled executable, but not when running with the visual studio debugger.  I'm using 2019 community.